# Ubuntu Mysql version 4.1.22 and 5.6 on same server

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me how to install MySql Server version 4 and version 5 on same Ubuntu 15.10. server?

Thanks

Comment: This question is off-topic for various reasons: too broad, not directly related to programming but networking-related, and shows no effort from you.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same requirement. There are several solutions for this problem. So we simply used the docker to solve this. I needed 5.7 and 5.6 for my purpose,Simply replace the version number you need.

First install mysql 5.6 via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
```

Then install docker if it is not installed prior with this command

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Then download and run the docker for the 5.6 version

```
sudo docker run --name mysql-56-container -p 127.0.0.1:3320:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.6
```

Now the mysql 5.6 version is running in the 3320 port, connect to the DB by this command.

```
mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3320
```

and connect to the 5.7 version using this command

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

It is given in the mysql docs :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: Do you have any ideas where from can i download mysql version 4.1.22 binary files ?

Comment: http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/mysql/4.1.22#package_detail_tabs

http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/downloads/mysql/4.1.html